# SimpleInjector: The configuration is invalid. The type is directly or indirectly depending on itself

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, injeção-de-dependência, ioc, simple-injector

Estou com o seguinte problema ao aplicar o container SimpleInjector em uma aplicação simples:

```
The configuration is invalid. 
The type BookAppService is directly or indirectly depending on itself. 
The cyclic graph contains the following types: BookAppService -> BookAppService -> BookAppService.
```

Essa é a classe BookAppService:

```
public class BookAppService : AppServiceBase<Book>, IBookAppService
{
    private readonly IBookAppService _bookService;

    public BookAppService(IBookAppService bookService) : base(bookService)
    {
        _bookService = bookService;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Book> GetSpecialBooks(IEnumerable<Book> books)
    {
        return _bookService.GetSpecialBooks(_bookService.GetAll());
    }
```

E essa é a configuração do SimpleInjectorInitializer:

```
container.Register(typeof(IAppServiceBase<>), typeof(AppServiceBase<>));
container.Register<IBookAppService, BookAppService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Sou bem iniciante em IoC e DI, e agradeço por qualquer ajuda e dica. Obrigado.

Comment: Você precisa colocar `AppServiceBase<>` e `IBookAppService` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está pedindo uma instancia de `BookAppService` dentro de uma instância dela mesmo, causando recursão infinita.

Isso não faz muito sentido, você pode acessar a instancia atual utilizando o `this` e o `AppServiceBase` herdado utilizando `base`.